# How to convert MTIFF to PNG with ImageMagick with a specific output filename format?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I know the ImageMagick convert command can convert a single multipage TIFF to multiple PNG files.

What convert command-options allow me to specify the output filename format?

Based on my research, I tried the options below with no success.

```
convert original.tif -format PNG -set filename:area '%t-PAGE-%p' "%[filename:area]"
```

If the original.tif file contains 3 pages, I expect 3 new PNG files with filenames:

```
original-PAGE-0.PNG
original-PAGE-1.PNG
original-PAGE-2.PNG
```

**NOTE** I learned that prior to ImageMagick ver 6.2, output filenames were formatted `<original_filename>.<format_suffix>.<image_number>`.  This caused issues due to the suffix being the image number, so, with ver 6.2 and on, output filenames are now formatted `<original_filename>-<image_number>.<format_suffix>`!

e.g. image.png.0 vs. image-0.png

Comment: Not at a computer but probably `convert input.tif original-PAGE-%d.PNG`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you!  That works for a single TIFF.  

What if I am trying to convert multiple TIFF files?

For example, assume I now have files original1.tif and original2.tif and both contain 3 images each.

What command would convert both TIFF files at once into 6 PNG files (original1-PAGE-1.PNG, original1-PAGE-2.PNG, original1-PAGE-3.PNG, original2-PAGE-1.PNG, original2-PAGE-2.PNG, original2-PAGE-3.PNG)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to update to a newer version of ImageMagick (v6.2 or newer) since prior to ImageMagick ver 6.2, the page number was the suffix in the output filename:

`<original_filename>.<format_suffix>.<image_number>`

`e.g. image.png.0`

Starting with IM 6.3, the page number was moved before the filename suffix:

`<original_filename>-<image_number>.<format_suffix>`

`e.g. image-0.png`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on IM 6.9.10.68 Q16 Mac OSX. Just add your suffix. Each tif below is made up of 3 pages.

```
convert logo1.tif logo2.tif -set filename:fn '%t-PAGE-%p' "%[filename:fn].png"
```

However, the numbering on the results is sequential even though the names are different.

```
logo1-PAGE-0.png
logo1-PAGE-1.png
logo1-PAGE-2.png
logo2-PAGE-3.png
logo2-PAGE-4.png
logo2-PAGE-5.png
```

I do not know that you can do otherwise with convert.

**Another way to approach it,** is to put your several images into a folder (I use test1) and use mogrify. Then create a new directory to hold the output (I use test2). Then cd to the input image folder. Then run:

```
mogrify -path ../test2 -format png *.tif
```

That produces:

```
logo1-0.png
logo1-1.png
logo1-2.png
logo2-0.png
logo2-1.png
logo2-2.png
```

Unfortunately, mogrify is not as flexible as convert and does not support -set filename. But at least you now get numbering from -0 for each image.

Comment: Unfortunately, on my Solaris 10 host, your `convert` command suggestion results in output files with the name %[filename:fn] as the actual literal name.

Your `mogrify` command suggestion works fine, but I don't have the ability to control the filename.

Comment: How old is your Imagemagic version? If may predate the -set filename protocol. Perhaps you should look into an upgrade.

Comment: It's ver 6.3.4 and the options screen includes `-set property value  set an image property`

Comment: That version is ancient. What is the date associated with that version. Linux systems patch without changing the number so it could be more recent. But by version it is over 650 versions old. It could be prior to the -set filename. The % escapes in -set filename were not allowed before 6.4.8-4. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#save_escapes